# Imported fonts not loading from certain source

Tags: html, css, fonts

I apologize in advance for the generic examples of this since the issue is with a proprietary corporate system.

I support a web app that allows for edits to a secondary CSS file in order to style the page (within the limits of the application).  I'm trying to apply a non-standard font that is used company wide but I do not have access to edit the HTML or header of the site, only the CSS.  I tried declaring the font-family in the main CSS while referencing the actual font file URLs (since they are used on our corporate site) but they never actually loaded.

I then took the same font-family snippet and created a separate CSS file for just the font declaration and changed the URL to point to the actual files in the relative path (ex: url('fonts/DINWeb.woff') ).  I moved this fonts.css file along with the reference font files (eot, ttf,and woff versions) to a public Dropbox folder for testing.  I was able to get everything working by simply importing the fonts.css file using the line of code below (URL modified) at the top of my application's CSS.

```css
@import url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/.../fonts.css');
```

The problem is that the Dropbox solution was just for temporary testing purposes.  Once I confirmed everything worked as expected, I moved the exact folder structure to an external hosting location that is approved for use.  When I update my import code in the CSS to the new URL, the font does not load.  I can access the CSS file and the font files from my browser without any issue so I don't understand why the web app fails to load it.  I also have images hosted in this same hosting location that pull into the web app without an issue, it's only the font that has issues.  The files work when hosted on Dropbox but not the other source.  I've also double checked the references for the URL and they are still correct since the folder structure never changed.

Any suggestions would be GREATLY appreciated.  Ideally I would like to just reference the corporate URLs directly in the web app's CSS like I initially tried.  If that will not be possible, I need it to work with the externally hosted files since Dropbox cannot be used as the permanent solution.

Comment: After further digging I found that the font is getting blocked because "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin; header is present in the requested resource".  This is the first time I've dealt with this.  Any suggestions how I can add this to my requested files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you cannot load from one domain resources hosted in other domain, unless the second host says that you can. See [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

You can solve it by moving everything to the same domain (or forcing the user to be always in certain domain) or by adding the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to the responses.

You can achieve this last thing if you can edit an `.htaccess` file in the server. Add:

`Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`

Or replace the `*` with the domain from which you'll be making the requests.

Yes, a subdomain is a different domain (`abc.com`, `www.abc.com` and `dl.abc.com` are not the same).